# How to track scammers through etherscan?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, etherscan, transaction-trace

I just came across this video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhkb9G2SyVw
Wich have this code in the description:
https://pastebin.com/raw/U8FQewES

It seems quite attractive at first, but the more you investigate, the more murky it becomes. Upon investigating the code provided in the description for you to copy and paste, send your ETH to the contract, and then "generate money," I have seen that it is nothing more than a convoluted way to make you send your ETH to the scammer's wallet. Making a simple test you can easily see that `start()` and `withdrawal()` just return a really well hidden scammers address for you to send him your money.

This is the scammers address i manage to reverse-engineered from the code:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xbcf87a18e05e562bd307d76682677d2388973cc6
Following the withdrawals all of them converge here:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x077d360f11d220e4d5d831430c81c26c9be7c4a4 a 40ETH address wich probably is owned by a group of scammers.

I dont have enough knowledge to continue following the breadcrumbs because at this point it gets messy and I hope that given this information someone here can continue from where I left and maybe trace this mother****s.
IDK, maybe is hopeless but I wanted to give it a try with the community.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is obviously a scam. Video with distorted voice, pastebin link taken down, all is from people making money, none of them failed. Just ask yourself if they are making so much money why they will publish the source code for free?

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is many scammer and its easy to track them just follow transfers .. **from** (scammer addresss) > **to** (another wallet of scammer).

So if you follow each transfer the scammer make, **one moment** you gonna a transfer **to an exchange** plateform for sure ...

Many blockchain is public so everybody can trust absolutly anything ..

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone can create almost unlimited addresses (and anyone could be behind an address), you **cannot** trace the address further than that. As long as it's laying there, noone can do anything about that. Although it might not seem like it, this is is a major advantage of the blockchain. Since noone can move the funds except for you, it is truly yours.

The good thing though is, that the scammers have access to the funds but, they will have trouble actually withdrawing these or turning these into something useful (technically, since [Tornado Cash](https://tornadocash.eth.link/) is illegal). Since the only way are Centralized Exchanges like Kraken or Binance and all of these require identification and are heavily regulated by the government. However, until the funds are not moved, there is nothing anyone can do.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake and tryed it aswell, but somehow I was able to withdraw my initial 0.1eth from the contract which I made for a test so, I hope there could be a way to get the funds back somehow ?

Comment: Can you show the process you have followed? Most scam contracts only allows the scammer to withdraw funds.

Comment: Here is my contract address : https://etherscan.io/address/0x3EBcc3acf2A1D0cdc50BcD73C4a4AF475Fe06d32

Comment: I send 0.1 eth to the contract, than withdraw it again - all was normal, than I send about 0.4 eth again, it made one swap, or maybe some fake swap transaction, and after that it stopped , so I read the manual again, and it said to start again to check for errors, than it said to add more eth..

Comment: Can you verify the smart contract source code? Scammers could make the contract to change behavior when depositing a small amount, and block themselves if you deposited a large amount. In any case the contract published in the question is a scam, you shouldn't deploy it you are risking your money.

Comment: The code above is not available anymore..

Comment: Sorry, but I would doubt any assertion that withdrawals are feasible if you can't provide a proof. You should **never** interact with a contract you cannot validate.

Comment: I understand, but I posted my contract address above already, where you can see in the history that I actually did withdraw from the contract .. here’s the address again https://etherscan.io/address/0x3EBcc3acf2A1D0cdc50BcD73C4a4AF475Fe06d32

Comment: I also made a Post with my code here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150250/frontrunning-bot-scam?noredirect=1#comment168399_150250 but no one want to check my code.. so it was closed very quickly. The code provided here (post on the top) is not available anymore on Postbin, so I can’t validate if it’s the same code I used..

Comment: Thank you for your efforts!